# properties applying only after mouse click in datagrid in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

i used code like this to change color of cell but properties applying only after mouse click but i want change color after form loaded

### Used Code

```
    private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int j = 6;
            DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            dataGridView1[j, i].Style = CellStyle;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `this.Update()` of `(DataGridView)sender.Update()` after for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that code from `dataGridView1_RowValidated` and add it to form `Load` event instead:

Add this code in the form constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponents();

    this.Load += OnFormLoad;
    this.dataGridView1.Sorted += OnDataGridSorted;
}

private void OnFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateDataGridViewColor();
}

private void OnDataGridSorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateDataGridViewColor(); 
}

private void UpdateDataGridViewColor()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int j = 6;
        DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView1[j, i].Style = CellStyle;
    }
}
```

Note also you can add form Load event by double click on the form designer..

**Edit:** you stated in comments that when you click column to sort the applying color will removed. to fix that add `this.dataGridView1.Sorted += OnDataGridSorted;` event so whenever sorted is done the new style is applied. the code above updated. "btw: I don't tested it, till me if it not worked.."

Comment: ya its working but when i click on column header for sorting style is not applying

Comment: @Chandan: what is the code you run when `sorting the formatting style`?

Comment: i am not written any code for sorting, i just clicking on column header to sorting

Comment: i mean when form loads fore color color changes correctly but when i click on any of column header in data grid then fore color changes to black and no red